# Flashdevelop + haxe -- repeated "An I/O error has occured" errors

Tags: io, flashdevelop, haxe

I'm getting small dialog boxes that pop up saying `I/O Error occurred`. What causes this, and how should I fix this?

Edit: what happens is that after i run my flash game, FlashDevelop will try to connect to the Flash debugger, but apparently fail and give me the above error. I have both the debug standalone player and the ActiveX debug control for Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To activate interactive debugging with haxe/Flash/FlashDevelop you have to add the fdb switch and network-sandbox. To do that open Project -> Properties -> Compiler Options -> Directives and add the following two lines:

```
fdb
network-sandbox
```

That should be all you need. After that you should be able to set breakpoints, inspect object fields and local variables and profile your code.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have haxe, but I had the same error and to get rid of it I followed [the advice from here](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=7083):

> Specify the path to the debug player
>   (flashplayer_10_sa_debug.exe or
>   FlashPlayerDebug.exe in the SDK) in
>   FlashDevelop Tools > Program settings > FlashViewer